# Power BI Matrix Viz: Highlighting Cells on the Right Side of Intersection Between Rows and Columns

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I want to **highlight the cells on the right side of intersection between rows and columns** to indicate the respondents who are willing to spend more money than they've ever spent the most for a cup of coffee. How to achieve this using DAX formula or other workaround(s)?

my current matrix visualization and what I want to achieve (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRRPn.png)

Thank you beforehand!

I've tried searching the solution on internet and using AI chatbot to look for the solution but to no avail